# Change Google Drive file from public to private

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I created a public File on my Google Drive, I used the v3 API from Google Drive on Python to get a list of all my files.

Now I want to change a file permissions so it would be private and can only be seen by me (owner)

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

# Setup the Drive v3 API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_id.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Drive v3 API
results = service.files().list(
    pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, modifiedTime, owners, permissions)").execute()
items = results.get('files', [])
if not items:
    print('No files found.')
else:
    print('Files:')
    for item in items:
        print('{0} ({1}) ({2})'.format(item['name'], item['id'], item["modifiedTime"])


Cosa = items[2]
print("--- Archivo Publico ---")
print(Cosa["permissions"])

print("---- Modifico los Permisos ----")

service.permissions().delete(fileId="ExampleID",permissionId="anyone").execute()
```

Now, when I execute the code I get:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1KHjbcJkN79cccgwywrwsBHlOuLUgtOqXZk4gvZKR1eE/permissions/anyone? returned "Insufficient Permission">
```

Why? I´m the owner of the File.

edit: The file has 2 permissions. The first is "anyone" which let´s everyone see and edit the file. The second is my permission which makes me the owner. I'm trying to delete the first to make the file private

Comment: Have you referred the below url - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing

Comment: I have seen it, and it says "To revoke access to an item, delete the permission", and thats what I´m trying to do. I´m trying to delete the permission "anyone" wich is the one that let´s everyone see the File on the web

Comment: that looks like you are authenticating using a Service Account, in which case the Service Account is *not* the owner of the file in your personal Google Account

Comment: @pinoyyid yep, you were right. I deleted my credentials.json and change the SCOPE from auth/drive.metadata.readonly to auth/drive and it worked as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change de SCOPE from:

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
```

to

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
```

I also deleted my credentials.json and made the web authentication. It works as spected now